# How to count inner joined table rows in Doctrine query builder or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to figure out how to count instalments attached to the contract and then return it in the result if there are less than 2.

```php
    ->select('cc')
    ->addSelect('COUNT(cci) AS HIDDEN numberOfInstalments')
    ->from('AppBundle:ClientContract', 'cc')
    ->innerJoin('AppBundle:ClientContractInstalment', 'cci', 'WITH', 'cci.clientContract = cc')
    ->andHaving('numberOfInstalments < :numberOfRequiredInstalments'(
    ->setParameter('numberOfRequiredInstalments', 2)
    ->getResult()
```

The code from above works well when I add one `ClientContract`, but the problem gets when I add more client contracts, then `COUNT(cci)` counts all instalments instead of per `ClientContract`.

How can I change this, so `COUNT(cci)` will count instalments inside the ClientContract and if less than 2, return in the result?

Comment: Try adding `group by` clause

Comment: GroupBy what did you put to make it work?

Comment: @metafa In my case I grouped by "cc"